# Python(beginner), I dont understand difference between two of these

Tags: python, loops, break

I dont understand difference between two of these. Why output is not the same

```
 x = 0
for i in range(10):
    x += i
    while True:
        if x < 10:
            print('Hi')
            print('Hello')
            break
    print(x)


>>Hi
>>Hello
>>0
>>Hi
>>Hello
>>1
>>Hi
>>Hello
>>3
>>Hi
>>Hello
>>6
```

and the another one

```
x = 0
for i in range(10):
    x += i
    while x < 10:
        print('Hi')
        print('Hello')
        break
    print(x)


>>Hi
>>Hello
>>0
>>Hi
>>Hello
>>1
>>Hi
>>Hello
>>3
>>Hi
>>Hello
>>6
>>10
>>15
>>21
>>28
>>36
>>45
```

I dont understand about `break` statement. the first one, it seem like it break out of for loop  but the second one it only break out while loop inside for loop.

I'm so beginner on learning these language, Im sry if this question look silly :X

Comment: just check the condition in while loop. in the first code while loop is infinite but because of it will break at first iteration only

Comment: Are you sure you want while loops?  It seems those are just if-blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Both break statements are breaking the while loop. If you look closely, the first program isn't exiting the for loop, but is instead running indefinitely inside the while loop (because x is not less than 10 at that point (0 1 3 6 10), so the if branch never gets executed and the while True loop keeps running), hence not printing subsequent x values as you'd expect in the for loop.

Comment: thank you so much, now i understand what wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

In the first script, the 'break' is reached only when the 'x < 10' condition is met which will break the while-loop. In this case, only the 4 first iterations of the for-loop are printed, then the while-loop becomes an infinite loop. On the second script, the break is reached after each while until the 4th iteration of the for-loop while 'x < 10', then it won't get into that cycle again since the following values of x are greater than 10. Break statement breaks from the nearest loop.